# Asterisk Hold event via IAX2 and SIP

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I have two phones one using IAX2 second SIP. When I press Hold button on IAX2 phone I get Asterisk event "Hold", When I press Hold button on SIP Phone I get Unlink then Bridge event. Can I change this behavior for SIP phone to get "Hold" event from Asterisk? Why SIP phone not send one "Hold" event?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What version of Asterisk are you using?

A re-INVITE coming from a SIP UA notifying Asterisk to put the channel on hold should not unlink a bridge with another channel, unless the hold from the re-INVITE is asking it to do something other the just simply restrict the flow of the RTP.

You may want to post this on issues.asterisk.org/jira.  If you do so, please include a DEBUG log, with sip set debug on, illustrating the problem.

Comment: Please do file this as an issue on issues.asterisk.org/jira.  Please include the DEBUG log, containing the SIP message trace using "sip set debug on".  Please also identify in the issue description the addresses of the endpoints that are in use.  You will also need to attach your iax.conf and sip.conf.  Thanks!